# Trouble appending elements to an array

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift4

I am trying to take data from my firebase, push it into an array, and then put it on a table view. The problem is that when I print the array, the console shows the array has nothing inside.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("Events").observe(.value, with: {(data) in
    let events = data.value as! NSDictionary
    for event in events {
        let dict = event.value as? [String : Any]
        print(dict?["EventTitle"]) 
        self.eventsArray.append(dict?["EventTitle"] as! String)
    }
)} 
print(eventsArray)
```

This code is in my `viewDidLoad` of the class for the UITableViewController. The array is defined above the viewDidLoad method as `var eventsArray = [String]()`

This is my firebase data:
[image]

Right now I am just trying to access the EventTitle and paste it in a table view, but before that, I need to put it in an array, which as you can see is not working.

Comment: Can you try to print all the keys in the dictionary so that we can better diagnose the issue?

Comment: Sorry for not putting that before, but the solution posted below worked, so I am going to stick with that

Answer (score 1):

`observe` works asynchronously. Put the `print` line in the completion block.

And use the appropriate dictionary enumeration API and Swift native types

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("Events").observe(.value, with: {(data) in
    let events = data.value as! [String:[String:String]]
    for (_, value) in events {
        print(value["EventTitle"]) 
        self.eventsArray.append(value["EventTitle"]!)
    }
    print(eventsArray)
)}
```

Consider to use an array for the events rather than a dictionary

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am really new to this stuff, as I am in 9th grade.

Comment: When I print eventsArray outside of the closure, it shows the array as empty, which means I cannot fix populate a table view with this, what should I do?

Comment: Do all the things you have to do (assigning the result to the data source and reloading the table view) inside the closure.